# Postgresql and populating the table with data based on existing records in the same table

Tags: postgresql

There is a modes table that has different attributes
**link**, **name** , **antoherAtrr**.

**link**, **name** - string values and unique

The task is to query all the existing rows in the table and multiply them by **N**-numbers entries, and insert them into the same table, but at the same time, so that the link, name-fields have a unique value(for example, add to the existing values in these fields + random number in a string)

```sql
insert into modes (link, name , antoherAtrr)
                                 select * from modes
```

This code will give an error, because the uniqueness of the first 2 columns is violated.

- modes

```sql
create table if not exists modes
(
    link varchar,
    name varchar,
    "anotherAtrr" integer
);

alter table modes owner to postgres;

create unique index if not exists modes_link_uindex
    on modes (link);

create unique index if not exists modes_name_uindex
    on modes (name);
```

[image]

and than must be

[image]

**N** is the number of rows that I would like to get in a single query ( i.e. duplicate rows based on the available ones, but considering the uniqueness of some attributes)

Who has any ideas on how to write this ? Can you provide the code with explanations ?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join on a generate_series expression.

Step by step...

Create a table expression returning n rows with an integer field:

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series(0,4) AS ser(nr);
 nr 
----
  0
  1
  2
  3
  4
(5 rows)
```

modes contains:

```
SELECT * FROM modes;
 link | name | anotherAtrr 
------+------+-------------
 foo  | bar  |          42
(1 row)
```

Select everything from the existing table and cross join it with the generated data (`JOIN on true`):

```
SELECT * 
FROM modes 
JOIN  generate_series(0,4) AS ser(nr) ON true;
 link | name | anotherAtrr | nr 
------+------+-------------+----
 foo  | bar  |          42 |  0
 foo  | bar  |          42 |  1
 foo  | bar  |          42 |  2
 foo  | bar  |          42 |  3
 foo  | bar  |          42 |  4
(5 rows)
```

Now combine the fields by concatenating the numbers to the string values:

```
INSERT INTO modes (link, name , "anotherAtrr")
SELECT  t1.link ||'_'||ser.nr, t1.name||'_'||ser.nr , t1."anotherAtrr" 
FROM modes t1
JOIN generate_series(0,4) AS ser(nr)ON true;
```

Could also be written as:

```
WITH ser AS (
SELECT * FROM generate_series(0,4) AS nr
)
INSERT INTO modes (link, name , "anotherAtrr")
SELECT  t1.link ||'_'||ser.nr, t1.name||'_'||ser.nr , t1."anotherAtrr" 
FROM modes t1
JOIN ser ON true;
```

Unrelated:

double quoting identifiers creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: This works great, but is it possible to check before inserting that the values will not be duplicated. In this case, I need to know that the range from which the number is generated has not yet been used.

Comment: What is reported in this case by the expression. -  ON true; Please explain. (maybe it says that it is allowed to generate a number from the specified range ?)

Comment: @skyho you have unique constraints in place to ensure, values can't be duplicated. The same code will not work when executed a second time. If you want that, you would need a generated unique value instead of an integer series. - But then you should rethink your data model first...

Comment: Thanks. It need for testings. Those data will delete after.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a table with generated data and you want to control amount rows.
You also add parameters in function...

```sql
create table foo
(
    id   integer not null
        constraint foo_pkey
            primary key,
    name text,
    data timestamp
);
```

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_table_foo()
    RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE

    startId      INT;
    endId        INT;
    nameVar      TEXT;
    dateVar      TIMESTAMP;
    period       INT default 0;
    stepTimeZone INT default 0;
begin
    startId := 1;
    endId := 20;

    for idVar in startId..endId
        loop
            nameVar := md5(random()::text);
            stepTimeZone := 3;
            dateVar :=
                    (now()::timestamp with time zone +
                     make_interval(hours := stepTimeZone) +
                     make_interval(days := period)
                        );

            insert into foo(id, name, data) values (idVar, nameVar, dateVar);

            period := period + 1;
        end loop;
end ;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```